# How to display the latest records first in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have created a database in MySQL. When I try to get all the records for a table, the last-added records are displayed last. How can I efficiently display the latest records first, without using a datetime column? Adding a datetime column would mean reinitializing all tables, which seems too troublesome to me.

Comment: Relational databases do not have any inherent order. If you care about the order of the results, add a column that the order should depend on and use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Add an auto-incremented ID column.

Comment: @Barmar from my understanding a InnoDB table is ordered on the primary key or clustered index so it is not a heap.

Comment: That's a particular implementation, but I don't think you can depend on it in general, and certainly wouldn't expect a complex join to retain that order.

Comment: QUOTE: "_Adding a datetime column would mean reinitializing all tables, which seems too troublesome to me._" It should be possible to add a column without "reinitializing" all tables: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 2):

> How can I efficiently display the latest records first, without using
>   a datetime column?

If you have an auto increment ID column you could try ordering by the record ID in descending order.

e.g.

SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY id DESC;

Answer (score 0):

To follow on from the previous answer many ORMs inster CreatedAt and UpdatedAt columns. Slap an ORDER BY CreatedAt DESC and there you have it in the order you want and it's independent of the Id you use.

Answer (score 0):

does you table have a index? then you could

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY index DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY` on an appropriate (time-ordered) column. As stated above, you can use an auto-incremented primary key, however this doesn't allow you to select a date range.

FWIW, it's not difficult to add timestamp columns to existing tables, and you gain the ability to return rows within a range of dates.

Approximate syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name`
ADD COLUMN `created_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

ALTER TABLE `table_name`
ADD INDEX `created_time` (`created_time`);
```